# Exporting a Database schema and triggers

Tags: sql-server, export, toad

I have a small problem at work. Our DBA went on a journey of self-discovery ... I am very happy for him and I hope he finds what he is looking for. But he left us without any information about how the database he created works, the triggers he has, the connections between tables and, frankly, no documentation.

My question is whether it is possible to export all the information from the database (connections between tables, schema, triggers, fields with data type, etc .. :) in a file from TOAD or another application to mount it in some application that would reverse engineer the database to indicate that same information that we need.

I thank you very much for the help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

1. To find information about database object ( I am using triggers as example here )
   use TOAD 
   choose Triggers
   Right Click on Triggers
   Create Script

That will give you source for all triggers

Repeat this for all TABLES, INDEXES, SEQUENCES etc. After reverse engineering a few - you will get hang of it.

2. Connections between tables

I believe you mean "relations between tables". If you schema is small say a few tables, then you can browse thru Parent and Child option of each table and document them.

For large number of tables, you will need to use TOAD to create Data Model Diagram; or maybe google for "Data Modeling Tools" and find one that fits your needs and budget.

You will imperatively need to refer to data model diagram many times in your new roles - so do it patiently and correctly.